# Add sequence of dates to data.table (R)

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data table that contains locations of places that have recurring events at different frequencies. The date of the last event is provided, as well as how frequently it occurs.

Example:

```
dt
#    Location Last_Occurrence Frequency
# 1: Home     7-19-2018       30
# 2: School   6-6-2018        60
# 3: Moon     1-5-1993        90
```

What I would like to do is add a new column that includes all of the future event dates for each location up through the end of the year 2018.

So, I would like a table that looks something as follows:

```
dt
#    Location Last_Occurrence Frequency Next_Dates
# 1: Home     7-19-2018       30        7-19-2018
# 2: Home     7-19-2018       30        8-18-2018
# 3: Home     7-19-2018       30        9-17-2018
# 4: Home     7-19-2018       30        10-17-2018
# 5: Home     7-19-2018       30        11-16-2018
# 6: Home     7-19-2018       30        12-16-2018
# 7: School   6-6-2018        60        6-6-2018
# 8: School   6-6-2018        60        8-5-2018
# 9: School   6-6-2018        60        10-4-2018
etc.
```

How should I go about doing this? I suspect a lapply function would be useful, since I'm doing this over each location...

I've figured out how to use a "while" loop to generate a vector of future dates:

```
Last_Sample_Date <- Sys.Date() #For testing
increase <- 5 #For testing
NextDate <- Last_Sample_Date+increase
multiplier <- 1  

# Create vector of next sampling dates - updated with each iteration of the while loop
NextDates <- c(Last_Sample_Date, NextDate)

while (year(NextDate) == 2018) {
  multiplier <- multiplier+1
  NextDate <- NextDate+multiplier*increase

  #Add to vector of next sampling dates
  NextDates <- append(NextDates, NextDate)
})
```

(I realize this actually generates a vector containing the final date in 2019, but I'm OK with that.)

Could I use this while loop somehow, or is there another way I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version with data.table

```
library(data.table)

# create example dataset
dt <- data.table(
        location = c("home", "school", "moon"),
        orig_date = as.Date(c("2018-07-19", "2018-06-06", "2015-01-05")),
        freq_days = c(30, 60, 90)
)

# figure out how many new rows are needed
dt[ , rows_needed := length(seq(from=orig_date, to=as.Date("2018-12-31"), by=paste(freq_days,"days"))), by=location]

# expand the data.table to include the new rows
dt <- dt[rep(1:nrow(dt), times=rows_needed)]

# add the dates of occurrence
dt[ , date_of_occurrence := seq(from=orig_date[1], to=as.Date("2018-12-31"), by=paste(freq_days[1],"days")), by=location]

# shift dates of occurrence to get next date
dt[ , next_date := shift(date_of_occurrence, type="lead"), by=location]

# drop rows where next occurrence is after 2018 (should you want this)
dt <- dt[!is.na(next_date)]
```

Comment: Hi Dan - thanks for the help! I'm having trouble getting the "figure out how many new rows are needed" line to work. I'm pretty sure I'm entering it in correctly, but I get the following error:

`Error in seq.Date(from = orig_date[1], to = as.Date("2018-12-31"),  : 
  'by' is NA`

Any idea what is going on? I've tested it by running:
`seq(from=orig_date[1], to=as.Date("2018-12-31"), by=paste(freq_days,"days"))`

...and this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Check that your column freq_days doesn't have any NAs with something like `sum(is.na(dt$freq_days))` and check that you've attached the data.table package.  If the problem persists, email me your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for all your help! It worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, with `complete` from `tidyr`

```
df %>% group_by(Location,Frequency,Last_Occurrence) %>%
      mutate(next_date=Last_Occurrence)%>%
      complete(next_date=seq(from = next_date, to = as.Date("2018-12-31"),by = Frequency))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Location, Frequency, Last_Occurrence [2]
   Location Frequency Last_Occurrence  next_date
      <chr>     <int>          <date>     <date>
 1     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-07-19
 2     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-08-18
 3     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-09-17
 4     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-10-17
 5     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-11-16
 6     Home        30      2018-07-19 2018-12-16
 7   School        60      2018-06-06 2018-06-06
 8   School        60      2018-06-06 2018-08-05
 9   School        60      2018-06-06 2018-10-04
10   School        60      2018-06-06 2018-12-03
```